# Vacuum tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, vacuum

Using [postgresql-9.2](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.2),at this moment am finding the *tables* that have `dead_tuples` using the following *query*:

```sql
SELECT relname FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE n_dead_tup > 0
```

this will return the table name and then I'll run:

```sql
VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE <table_name>
```

---

Is that a good method or do I need to change it,if so please suggest me some methods

Thanks

Comment: What about auto vacuum? It should do this job by default

Comment: When I do `select * from pg_stat_user_tables ...` I can see `last_auto_vacuum` is a timestamp and it is `null` even when `autovacuum` is set to `on`.

Answer (score 4):

according to [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-vacuum.html)

> VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples.

But according to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14801/what-is-the-meaning-of-n-live-tup-and-n-dead-tup-in-pg-stat-user-tables)

> Dead rows are deleted rows that will later be reused for new rows from INSERTs or UPDATEs. Some dead rows (or reserved free space) can be particularly useful for HOT (Heap-Only Tuples) updates that can reuse space in the same data page efficiently

Comment: `Some dead rows...` others don't. Are you telling us to not vacuum ?

Comment: @MagnoC you have to use vacuum. Without vacuum for big databases, will be difficult to store and manage. Better to set correct settings for autovacuum and it will do by itself.